# No se imprime lista enlazada correctamente

Tags: java, lista

Cada nodo tiene tres datos, cuando se imprime solo se muestra el nodo actual.

```
package lista.enlazada1;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class ListaEnlazada1 {

    public String marca;
    public String modelo;
    public int kilometraje;
    public ListaEnlazada1 nodosiguiente;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* se ingresa la cantidad de nodos a crear */
        Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Digite la cantidad de nodos a ingresar)");
        int n, contador = 0;
        n = leer.nextInt();

        /* los tres datos del nodo son ingresados */
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            ListaEnlazada1 nodo = new ListaEnlazada1();
            System.out.print("ingrese la marca ");
            nodo.marca = leer.next();
            System.out.print("ingrese el modelo ");
            nodo.modelo = leer.next();
            System.out.print("ingrese el kilometraje ");
            nodo.kilometraje = leer.nextInt();

            /* el nodo es ceado*/
            if (contador == 0) {
                nodo.nodosiguiente = null;
                contador++;
            } else {
                nodo.nodosiguiente = nodo;
                contador++;
            }

            /* la lista entrelazada es imprimida*/
            for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
                System.out.println("marca " + nodo.marca + "\n");
                System.out.println("modelo " + nodo.modelo + "\n");
                System.out.println("kilometraje " + nodo.kilometraje + "\n");
                System.out.println("apuntador " + nodo.nodosiguiente + "\n");

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Como se crea una variable de incremento automático, ejemplo la variable se llama nodo, entonces se incrementa y se llama nodo1.
Debo crear una variable de incremento automático para poder imprimir todos los nodos

Comment: en tu ciclo no imprimes la lista. Imprimes el nodo actual (estas dentro el ciclo que lee e ingresa los datos del nodo). Ademas la linea `nodo.nodosiguiente = nodo;` asigna el nodo siguiente a si mismo :(

Comment: como hago para cambiar donde debo imprimir, se muestre todos los nodos?

Answer (score 0):

Buenas. Este es un ejemplo simple de como podría ser (pero no necesariamente está correcto y/o coincide con los algoritmos de una lista enlazada):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* se ingresa la cantidad de nodos a crear */
        Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Digite la cantidad de nodos a ingresar)");
        int n;

        do {
            n = leer.nextInt();
        } while (n < 1);

        /* los tres datos del nodo son ingresados */
        ListaEnlazada lista = null, ultimo = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.print("ingrese la marca ");
            String marca = leer.next();
            System.out.print("ingrese el modelo ");
            String modelo = leer.next();
            System.out.print("ingrese el kilometraje ");
            int km = leer.nextInt();

            if (i == 0) {
                // si es el inicio, se crea la lista y se asigna como ultimo elemento en la variable temporal
                ultimo = new ListaEnlazada(marca, modelo, km);
                lista = ultimo;
            } else {
                // despues del primer ciclo, en "ultimo" se crea el nuevo nodo (el primero si i=1), y luego se asigna el nuevo nodo como el ultimo
                ultimo.nodosiguiente = new ListaEnlazada(marca, modelo, km);
                ultimo = ultimo.nodosiguiente;
            }
        }

        ListaEnlazada temp = lista;
        while (temp != null){
            temp.imprimirNodo();
            // cambiar temp por el nodo que sigue en cada iteracion
            temp = temp.nodosiguiente;
        }
    }
}

class ListaEnlazada {

    public String marca;
    public String modelo;
    public int kilometraje;
    public ListaEnlazada nodosiguiente;

    public ListaEnlazada(String marca, String modelo, int kilometraje) {
        this.marca = marca;
        this.modelo = modelo;
        this.kilometraje = kilometraje;
    }

    public void imprimirNodo() {
        System.out.println("marca " + this.marca);
        System.out.println("modelo " + this.modelo);
        System.out.println("kilometraje " + this.kilometraje);
    }
}
```